LSTM, different size for feature set and target
I am trying to build a weather forecasting model.
X_train shape :(2970, 1, 9)  
 Y_train shape : (3299675, 1, 4)
I am following the (samples_count, timestep, features) rule. The samples_count are my number of data points (these are grids on the map, each grid is a location. There are 9 variables in feature set like temperature, pressure etc.. Target is also a grid of 3299675 points and 4 target variables.
My code
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Dense

# Define the number of features in the input and output sequences
n_input_features = 9
n_output_features = 4

# Define the encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(722, n_input_features))
encoder_lstm = LSTM(50, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Define the decoder
decoder_lstm = LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)

# The RepeatVector layer should be used in the following way:
# it repeats the encoder's output (which is a single vector, since return_sequences=False in the encoder)
decoder_inputs = RepeatVector(1000)(encoder_outputs)  # Repeat the encoder output 1000 times

decoder_outputs = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_output_features))  # Apply a dense layer to each of the 1000 timesteps
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn `encoder_inputs` into `decoder_outputs`
model = Model(encoder_inputs, decoder_outputs)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')```

I am getting error saying the shapes don't match.

Am I doing something wrong? Can LSTM handle this kind of data, if not what can I do to handle variable input and output length. Thank you.

